# django queryset method returning different results after update

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-1.5, chain

I am having unexpected results after trial-ing an upgrade from django 1.5.1 to 1.5.5 with a queryset method along the lines of:

```
mylist = college.department_set.active()
```

So active() is my queryset method that basically just does a further filter i.e:

```
class DepartmentQuerySet(QuerySet):
    def active(self):
        return self.filter(active=True)
```

I have 2 virtualenvs running one 1.5.1 (my original) and one 1.5.5. I have done a `pip --upgrade -r requirements.txt` on the 1.5.5, so other dependencies have been updated also. The original returns the active departments for the college selected however in the 1.5.5 version it returns all the active departments regardless of the college, however if i change the code to the following then it works as expected.

```
mylist = college.department_set.all().active()
```

I don't mind making this change if it is necessary but looking at the change notes i can't see where and why this problem is occurring?

Grateful for any help.
Mathew

Comment: How do you construct that queryset in the department_set manager?

Comment: Ah. It is using django-model-utils PassThroughManager: `objects = PassThroughManager.for_queryset_class(DepartmentQuerySet)()`. I have had a quick read through the changes since 1.4.0 of this and cannot see anything obvious that would cause this?